# Same image being shown when showing a modal via .sheet after iterating array

Tags: core-data, swiftui

In a swiftui app, I am iterating an array of entities and showing thumbmnail images and have it set up that when one is tapped, a detail view is shown with that particular full size image.  The problem is that it's always the most recent image being shown when going to the detail screen.

Main view:

```
   if documents.count > 0 {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(documents, id: \.self.id) {(doc: Document) in
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: doc.image)!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.showImageDetail = true

                    }
                    .padding(.all, 5)
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImageDetail, content: {
                        ImageViewDetail(image: UIImage(data: doc.image)!)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When ImageDetailView is shown, it's alway the most recent image saved.  Below is the detail view code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ImageViewDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var image: UIImage
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .padding()
                .scaledToFit()
                .scaleEffect(scale)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .gesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged {value in
                        self.scale = value.magnitude
                    }
                )

            HStack {
                Button("Back") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
                .buttonStyle(FillStyle(width: 86, height: 32))
                .padding(.trailing, 10)

                Button("Delete") {

                }
                .buttonStyle(FillStyle(width: 86, height: 32))
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Image", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I can't seem to see why the right image is not displayed by the ImageDetailView?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `Bool` state with a `Document?` state:

```swift
@State var selectedDocument: Document?

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        ForEach(documents, id: \.self.id) {(doc: Document) in
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: doc.image)!)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedDocument = doc
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(item: $selectedDocument) {
        ImageViewDetail(image: UIImage(data: $0.image)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help - this one seemed to do the trick!  Now I have to just study why it worked and understand it!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sheet can be only one in view hierarchy, so below it is relocated for `HStack` and it is needed to add member `currentImage`

Here is scratchy approach... (not tested - might be needed take care of optionals)

```
@State private var currentImage: UIImage = UIImage() // < needed optionals?
...

ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
    HStack {
        ForEach(documents, id: \.self.id) {(doc: Document) in
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: doc.image)!)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .scaledToFit()
            .onTapGesture {
                self.currentImage = UIImage(data: doc.image) ?? UIImage() // < current
                self.showImageDetail = true
            }
            .padding(.all, 5)
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showImageDetail, content: { // < one sheet
                ImageViewDetail(image: self.currentImage)
            })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asperi - will try out your answer as well!